# Filter dropdown option in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a dropdown on my vue component

```html
<select v-validate="'required'" id="role" name="role" v-model="user.role">
   <option value="">Select Role</option>

   <option :value="role.id" v-for="(role, index) in 
            roles" :role="role" :index="index" :key="role.id">
            {{role.name}} </option>
</select>
```

I do not want to show option where `role.id==1` and `role.id=2`

fetching data on mounted like this

```js
mounted(){
    const header = {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.sessionUserData,
     };
   axios.get('/api/backend/fetchrole', {headers: header}).then((response) => {
      this.roles = response.data;
   });
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: @ankitb: No i don't want to filter in api because this api is used in other places and there i need this role iu want to filter it in vue

Comment: You can create a computed roles array called something like `filteredRoles`  without those values and use that in your for loop instead of roles.

Comment: @bassxzero: can you please show with some example

Comment: @user3653474 grovskiy posted an example using computed.

Comment: Added example for use about which @bassxzero says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```html
<select v-validate="'required'" id="role" name="role" v-model="user.role">
  <option value="">Select Role</option>
  <option :value="role.id" v-for="(role, index) in formattedRoles" :role="role" :index="index" :key="role.id">{{role.name}}</option>
</select>
```

---

```js
computed: {
  formattedRoles() {
    return this.roles.filter(item => item.id !== 1 && item.id !== 2);
  },
}
```

**or**

```js
mounted() {
  const header = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.sessionUserData,
  };
  axios.get('/api/backend/fetchrole', { headers: header }).then((response) => {
    this.roles = response.data.filter(item => item.id !== 1 && item.id !== 2);
  });
},
```